# Remove characters before and after text string in files that don't have identical number of characters

Tags: regex, string, batch-file

I have a folder with PDF's I'm trying to rename. The naming structure is `XXX - XXX - YYY - XXX - XXX`. I want to keep the `YYY` portion, however my problem is the YYY string can vary in length and the `XXX` strings before and after can vary in length, so I can't tell the script delete x# of characters...

The only thing constant is the number of spaces before the `YYY` string. There are 5 spaces, my idea is to count to 5 spaces, save the next set of continuous characters (`YYY`) before the next space as my string to rename the file.

I'm vaguely aware of how to setup and run batch files, enough to know this should be possible, but very unqualified to figure it out. Any help would be great appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[This page](http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php) would be a great place to start.  I think what you're looking for is something like this:

```js
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for %%I in (*.pdf) do (
    set "pdffile=%%~nxI"
    set "begin=!pdffile:*     =!"
    set newname=
    for %%x in (!begin!) do if not defined newname set "newname=%%x"
    ren "%%~fI" "!newname!.pdf"
)
```

You could also use a rename utility capable of renaming based on regular expressions -- dbenham's [jren.bat](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6081) for example, or [`rename` from GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/util-linux-ng.htm) or [Flexible Renamer](http://hp.vector.co.jp/authors/VA014830/english/FlexRena/) to name a couple of others.